# Searching in a category filtered view

Tags: javascript, lotus-notes, xpages

I have a view that is categorized by Country and then sorted by customer name - customer name is not unique (it is the list of jobs, so customers appear often). I can filter the view easily with a dropdown by country. Now I want to search inside the filtered view for customer. What's the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most promising approach, but not fully happy with it yet:
- cache the countries (they don't change that often) to get a country selection
- sort the view (not categorize) by country and customer
- use a JSON datasource and a Dojo grid
- there set the search to a vector with Country and Customer
- Set exact match to false

It will start the grid at the customer but display more when you scroll down, but that's OK in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the *best* solution would be, but what I would try is a full text search on a view. Create a query like "FIELD country contains 'us' AND FIELD username contains 'andy'". The value for country is taken from the drop down, the value for username for a text field.

Comment: Thimo, FTSearch on a view is *VERY* slow. What happens under the hood: a FTSearch against the NSF is done, then every document initialized to see if it is in that view. This is specifically slow when you have lots of results but only want to show a subset (e.g. 1-20, 21-40)

Comment: Interesting, what do you consider "very slow"? I like to think a FTSearch on a view **with** an FT index is very fast. For instance an FTSearch on a DB with 6 million documents produces results in < 0.5s (just a few search results).

Comment: OK, let me specify the use case: if you search a FTSearch in a view where you get LOTS of hits - then it will start becoming slow. If the number of initial hits is small only a few documents get opened and it will be fast. I had a FTSearch in the NSF that resulted in about 50000 hits (< 0.5sec), the same in a view takes many minutes

Answer (score 0):

Based on my trials with this kind of functionality I believe the best approach is to manipulate a scoped collection/map of UNIDS as needed and then refresh a data table or repeat control as needed.  Beyond very simple requirements I have not seen a way to implement this functionality simply.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a collection with all the dropdown countries and do a search in the collection